# Typescript namespace containing a space

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings

I'm currently writing a typings file for an existing JavaScript library authored by another person. Unfortunately, they have an object where the keys contain spaces. An example:

```js
Example.object = {
    'ExampleA': {},
    'Another example': {},
    // so on
}
```

The `ExampleA` and `Another example` objects aren't empty but their contents are irrelevant here.

This is my first type actually writing a typing file so I may be doing this wrong, but how I'm writing it is like this (based on another typing file I'm using a base to follow along):

```
declare global {
    namespace Example {
        namespace object {
            namespace ExampleA {
                // ExampleA's contents here
            }
            namespace Another example {} // obviously an error
        }
    }    
}
```

How exactly would I namespace this object given it contains a space in its name? Am I going about writing this wrong?

Comment: What's its contents? does it have to be a namespace?

Comment: If that namespace doesn't have exported types just make it an object